# Carrito de compras con javascript a partir de una array

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo un *eCommerce* como tarea de la universidad **SIN PHP ni base de datos, solo con JAVASCRIPT**. Los productos deben ser generados dinámicamente a partir de un array. Tengo un *header*, un contador de cuantos productos hay en total y una navegación con tres categorías:*Todo*, *Hombre* y *Mujer* https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWHWB.png (foto para visualizar mejor). El **problema** es que solo pude cargar dinámicamente todos los productos y quiero que al presionar la categoría *Todo* *Hombre* o *Mujer* me cargue los productos correspondientes.

```js
let aRelojes = [
    {
        imagen: './img/buzo-adidas.jpg',
        nombre: 'Rolex',
        categoria:'Hombre',
        precio: 4999,
        descripcion:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum deserunt.',
    },
    {
        imagen: './img/buzo-adidas.jpg',
        nombre: 'Rolex',
        categoria:'Mujer',
        precio: 4999,
        descripcion:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum deserunt.',
    },
    {
        imagen: './img/buzo-adidas.jpg',
        nombre: 'Rolex',
        categoria:'Hombre',
        precio: 4999,
        descripcion:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum deserunt.',
    },
    {
        imagen: './img/buzo-adidas.jpg',
        nombre: 'Rolex',
        categoria:'Mujer',
        precio: 4999,
        descripcion:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum deserunt.',
    },
    {
        imagen: './img/buzo-adidas.jpg',
        nombre: 'Rolex',
        categoria:'Hombre',
        precio: 4999,
        descripcion:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum deserunt.',
    },
    {
        imagen: './img/buzo-adidas.jpg',
        nombre: 'Rolex',
        categoria:'Mujer',
        precio: 4999,
        descripcion:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum deserunt.',
    },
];



let cantRelojes=document.querySelector('.titulo_marca_block p');
cantRelojes.innerHTML=`${aRelojes.length} productos`;

let aHombre = aRelojes.filter(reloj => reloj.categoria === 'Hombre');
const mujer = aRelojes.filter(relojRolex => relojRolex.categoria === 'Mujer');


/*
//maquetación literal
<figure>
<picture>
<img src="" alt="">
</picture>
<figcaption>
<h3>Nombre del Producto</h3>
< p>Categoría</p>
<p>$300</p>
</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
*/

let relojes=document.querySelector('#relojes_js');
function CrearRelojes(){
    for (let reloj of aRelojes) {
        let figure=document.createElement('figure');
        relojes.appendChild(figure);

        let picture=document.createElement('picture');
        figure.appendChild(picture);

        let img=document.createElement('img');
        picture.appendChild(img);

        let figcaption=document.createElement('figcaption');
        figure.appendChild(figcaption);

        let titulo=document.createElement('h3');
        figcaption.appendChild(titulo);

        titulo.innerHTML=reloj.nombre;
        let categoria=document.createElement('p');

        categoria.innerHTML=reloj.categoria;
        figcaption.appendChild(categoria);

        let precio=document.createElement('p');
        precio.innerHTML=`$${reloj.precio}`;
        figcaption.appendChild(precio);      
    }
};

CrearRelojes();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rolex</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/estilos.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <a href="#" class="flecha">atras</a>
        <div class="buscar">buscar</div>
    </header>
    <div class="scroll_vertical">
        <div class="titulo_marca padding">
            <div class="titulo_marca_block">
                <h1>Rolex</h1>
                <p>X productos</p>
            </div>
            <picture>
                <img src="" alt="">
            </picture>
        </div>
        <nav id="list_menu">
            <ul class="padding">
                <li>
                    <a>Todo</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>Hombre</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>Mujer</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <section id="relojes_js" class="productos productos_vertical padding">

        </section>

    </div>
    <nav id="tab_menu">
        <ul>
            <li id="home_icono">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li id="carrito_icono">
                <a href="#carrito">Carrito</a>
            </li>
            <li id="favoritos_icono">
                <a href="#favoritos">Favoritos</a>
            </li>
            <li id="usuario_icono">
                <a href="#usuario">Usuario</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </nav>
    <script src="./js/carrito.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Que error tienes no explicas eso

Comment: @DavElsanto Lo explica en su pregunta:  _El problema es que solo pude cargar dinámicamente todos los productos y quiero que al presionar la categoría Todo Hombre o Mujer me cargue los productos correspondientes_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de una manera sencilla, con [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) para encontrar las coincidencias de elementos dentro de un array

Usaremos una clase a los elementos que se hacen click para filtrar, recorremos cada elemento y le añadimos un *eventListener*, al hacer click, reemplazamos los espacios y saltos de línea con una *expresión regular*

Incluso simplificando un poco el código, se puede reducir a que la función *CrearRelojes* opere el *filter* y también la carga de productos, pasándole como parámetro el array que recorreremos

```js
let aRelojes = [
    {
        imagen: './img/buzo-adidas.jpg',
        nombre: 'Rolex',
        categoria:'Hombre',
        precio: 4999,
        descripcion:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum deserunt.',
    },
    {
        imagen: './img/buzo-adidas.jpg',
        nombre: 'Rolex',
        categoria:'Mujer',
        precio: 4999,
        descripcion:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum deserunt.',
    },
    {
        imagen: './img/buzo-adidas.jpg',
        nombre: 'Rolex',
        categoria:'Hombre',
        precio: 4999,
        descripcion:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum deserunt.',
    },
    {
        imagen: './img/buzo-adidas.jpg',
        nombre: 'Rolex',
        categoria:'Mujer',
        precio: 4999,
        descripcion:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum deserunt.',
    },
    {
        imagen: './img/buzo-adidas.jpg',
        nombre: 'Rolex',
        categoria:'Hombre',
        precio: 4999,
        descripcion:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum deserunt.',
    },
    {
        imagen: './img/buzo-adidas.jpg',
        nombre: 'Rolex',
        categoria:'Mujer',
        precio: 4999,
        descripcion:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum deserunt.',
    },
];

let relojes=document.querySelector('#relojes_js');
function CrearRelojes(arr){
  let cantRelojes=document.querySelector('.titulo_marca_block > p');
  cantRelojes.innerHTML=`${arr.length} productos`;
    for (let reloj of arr) {
        let figure=document.createElement('figure');
        relojes.appendChild(figure);

        let picture=document.createElement('picture');
        figure.appendChild(picture);

        let img=document.createElement('img');
        picture.appendChild(img);

        let figcaption=document.createElement('figcaption');
        figure.appendChild(figcaption);

        let titulo=document.createElement('h3');
        figcaption.appendChild(titulo);

        titulo.innerHTML=reloj.nombre;
        let categoria=document.createElement('p');

        categoria.innerHTML=reloj.categoria;
        figcaption.appendChild(categoria);

        let precio=document.createElement('p');
        precio.innerHTML=`$${reloj.precio}`;
        figcaption.appendChild(precio);      
    }
};

CrearRelojes(aRelojes);

document.querySelectorAll(".filterSec").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const toFilter = el.textContent.replace(/[\n]|[ ]/g, "");
    relojes.innerHTML="";
    if(toFilter.toLowerCase()==="todo")return CrearRelojes(aRelojes);
    CrearRelojes(aRelojes.filter(obj=> obj.categoria === toFilter))
  });
});
```

```css
.filterSec {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rolex</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/estilos.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <a href="#" class="flecha">atras</a>
        <div class="buscar">buscar</div>
    </header>
    <div class="scroll_vertical">
        <div class="titulo_marca padding">
            <div class="titulo_marca_block">
                <h1>Rolex</h1>
                <p>X productos</p>
            </div>
            <picture>
                <img src="" alt="">
            </picture>
        </div>
        <nav id="list_menu">
            <ul class="padding">
                <li class="filterSec">
                    <a>Todo</a>
                </li>
                <li class="filterSec">
                    <a>Hombre</a>
                </li>
                <li class="filterSec">
                    <a>Mujer</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <section id="relojes_js" class="productos productos_vertical padding">

        </section>

    </div>
    <nav id="tab_menu">
        <ul>
            <li id="home_icono">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li id="carrito_icono">
                <a href="#carrito">Carrito</a>
            </li>
            <li id="favoritos_icono">
                <a href="#favoritos">Favoritos</a>
            </li>
            <li id="usuario_icono">
                <a href="#usuario">Usuario</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </nav>
    <script src="./js/carrito.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, sin embargo, [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) es mejor opción.

Comment: @Triby Gracias por los comentarios, he hecho la corrección